# I can't make this background img to cover the full height in desktop view

Tags: html, css

I've been searching in other questions since this is a pretty common problem but none of them applied to my case.

I'm developing a small web app with React, just to get the basics, and the background img works fine in mobile view (there's a media query that changes it at 480px to a portrait one) it resizes from 480px to 320 and looks good.

The problem is that, at certain heights if you stretch or wide the window the background gets stucked in the middle of it (if you recharge the page it appears as it should, being the window in the same exact place as where the problem occurs).

The img is loaded through CSS in the html, If I remove the `background-size` property it works as expected in desktop and mobile, but when I cross the 1260px width it doesnt cover the full width.

I have this codesandbox with all my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-brahmagupta-ro2kb?file=/src/style.css

And I attach an image of the problem. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: i'm having a hard time reproducing this effect. Can you give me the width and height to display in the inspector?

Comment: @snoh666 was right, content was overflowing, his answer is the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As u r testing this you can see the content of the App is overflowing the html element

I rather use min-height on global elements like body or html than static height to prevent such as cases.

So to fix it you just simply add

```
html {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
```

To prevent not overflowing instead of scaling we just add min-height equaly of 100vh (viewport height).

I think it will propably do the job without `height: auto;` but i like add it to prevent even more edge casing